# Error With Linking SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been working on a project for the past few months, and I am using SDL2, SDL2_image, and SDL2_TTF for the GUI portion of the project. In the past I have been using a Makefile to compile my code, but I have recently added extra dependencies and in the new libraries docs, it says that CMake should be used to build the project. Included below is the CMakeLists.txt file that I am using.

```
#Set required CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#Set project name
project(EXEC)

#
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

#
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

#Find Required Packages
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

#Set appropriate include directories
include_directories(include)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#Executable
add_executable(EXEC ${SOURCES})

#Perform Linking
target_link_libraries(EXEC ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I have created a CMakeLists.txt file, and it configures and generates with no issue, and by checking CMakeCache.txt I was able to verify that it has detected the directories of SDL2_image.so and SDL2_ttf.so. However, when I try to run the make command after generating, the resulting executable will not draw any text or loaded images to the screen. There are no errors in the compilation or any other steps of the process. When compiling with my old Makefile everything works fine, so I am assuming it must be a linker issue. Why is this happening and how can the issue be resolved?

Comment: "When compiling with my old Makefile everything works fine, so I am assuming it must be a linker issue." - Aside the "linker issue" there are many possible reasons of unexpected behavior. E.g. it could be that you incorrectly translate Makefile to CMake. Or your C++ code has defects which becomes exposed after slight modification of compiler/linker setup. So, what actually your program does instead of drawing? Does it returns the non-zero exit code? Have you tried to run `ldd` on your resulted executable for check whether correct libraries are picked at runtime?

Comment: Please, prepare [mcve]. Without the code it is impossible to help you.